# how to install and instantiate java chaincode in a peer that can't access to Internet ？

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The peer node can't access to internet,so how can i install and instantiate the java chaincode? As I know,install and instantiate must download the jar and gradle to the chaincode container?

Comment: Please show us what code / work you've started

Comment: Thank you for your response.I think what code is not the key.I want to know how can I install and instantiate  java chaincode without download associated jars from maven repository .Can i put the jar which the java chaincode  import to local maven folder and then don't need to download import jar ？

Comment: I am in the same situation as you. Have you managed to find an answer for this?